# Popular Custom-Views for Android - Any good Source?

Tags: android, frameworks, open-source, android-view

I was wondering if there is **any collection of good custom views for android available in the internet**?

I know about [androidviews](http://www.androidviews.net/) but their last update is more than 1,5 months ago.
This [statistic](http://www.appbrain.com/stats/libraries/dev) shows the most used frameworks in a list. But especially for unknown frameworks it's not a good source.

Most of the time I'm starting to develop something to find exactly my requirements in a framework a few weeks afterwards. This is a huge waste of time and I like to change this ;)

Where do you get your frameworks from? Volley, NineOld, ActionBarSherlock, PagerSlidingTabStrip and many others are very popular, but how do you know that they exist without asking everytime on stackoverflow?

I know about the search-function on GitHub but it's not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for a list of Frameworks, probably sorted by specific categories ("Grid", "ActionBar")...

Otherwise: I thought about opening a frequently updating thread about all frameworks user currently use. Is this possible in stackoverflow? Haven't seen it so far...

***Merry Christmas***

I hope the question won't be closed as off-topic - even if it's about asking for frameworks. This can be helpful for every android-developer.

Comment: Even if useful, it's still off-topic. If you want to change what's on- and off-topic, go to meta.stackoverflow.com and have the community agree with you.

Comment: I know it's off-topic. But how many people are asking questions for implementing things other people already implemented months before? Mostly it's not because they want to implement their own framework but more about the lack of knowledge they have about the range of different frameworks :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I subscribe to [AndroidWeekly](http://androidweekly.net/) and follow these guys on twitter:

- [Jake Wharton](https://twitter.com/JakeWharton)
- [Jeff Gilfelt](https://twitter.com/readyState)
- [Mark Murphy](https://twitter.com/commonsguy)
- [Romain Guy](https://twitter.com/romainguy)
- [Chet Haase](https://twitter.com/chethaase)
- [Jesse Wilson](https://twitter.com/jessewilson)
- [Koushik Dutta](https://twitter.com/koush)
- [Xavier Duchrohet](https://twitter.com/droidxav)
- [Brian Griffey](https://twitter.com/briangriffey)
- [Ty Smith](https://twitter.com/tsmith)
- [Christopher Jenkins](https://twitter.com/chrisjenx)
- [Cyril Mottier](https://twitter.com/cyrilmottier)
- [Manuel Peinado G.](https://twitter.com/mpg2)
- [Nicolas Pomepuy](https://twitter.com/PomepuyN)
- [Chris Lacy](https://twitter.com/chrismlacy)
- [Wolfram Rittemeyer](https://twitter.com/RittmeyerW)
- [Adam Koch](https://twitter.com/adamkoch)
- [Richard Hyndman](https://twitter.com/geekyouup)
- [Joaquim Vergès](https://twitter.com/joenrv)
- [Dave Smith](https://twitter.com/devunwired)
- [Donn Felker](https://twitter.com/donnfelker)
- [Novoda](https://twitter.com/novoda)
- [Roman Nurik](https://twitter.com/romannurik)
- [Ravi Tamada](https://twitter.com/RaviTamada)
- [Alex Lockwood](https://twitter.com/alexjlockwood)
- [Udi](https://twitter.com/Udinic)

That's enough to get my android dev news fix.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is a really interesting site! Even if my question will be closed it was worth asking it ;)

Comment: Thanks for the edited answer! I'll mark the question as solved - they'll close it anyway